# Bad pitch on outside water lines

Tags: plumbing

My plumbing system is copper.

I have an outside shower (OS) that can be isolated by a pair of shutoff valves (SV) in my bathroom vanity cabinet. The lines from those SV to the OS travel horizontally along the outside of the building for a bit, but they have a bad pitch, so can't be drained by gravity.

This winter I purged the lines by hooking an air compressor to the hose bib at the OS and pushing the water out through the bleeder ports on the SV. But because the SV is in a finished cabinet, it'd be less messy to push the water the other way next year; I'd like to hook a compressor to the bleeder ports of the SV and push the water out of the OS.

But what type of threads are on the bleeder ports? Are they usually national pipe threads (I suspect not but it's worth asking)? Have you ever hooked a compressor up to bleeder ports before?

Another thought is, rather than push the water with a compressor, pull the water with a pump. Although I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: Can you fix the pipe so that it drains better?

Comment: Or install a drain valve at the lowest point?

Comment: "What kind of threads?" without a picture, I'd guess round ones. Please [edit] your question to include a good, focused, reasonably close up picture of the threads in question. Someone here with good eyesight will probably be able to ID them for you.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.